# Erro ao adicionar ProgressDialog

Tags: android, dialog

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estou tendo problemas para adicionar uma dialog nesse metodo do listView, existe outra forma de fazer funcionar?

```
listDebitosPendentes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DetalhesDebitosActivity.this,
                             "Aguarde","Enviando Boleto....",true);
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
        Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetalhesDebitosActivity.class);
        //Passa para a activity o id no banco de dados
        intent.putExtra("ID",id);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Comment: Qual erro que ocorre?

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni, adicionei um print do erro na pergunta

Comment: Tenta deste jeito `android.app.ProgressDialog.show(...)`

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni, continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: Dei +1 apesar da música

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente com esse código para mostrar uma barra de progresso com tempo indeterminado que mostra um spinner:

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(DebitosPendentesActivity.this);

dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
dialog.setMessage("Enviando Boleto....");
dialog.setTitle("Aguarde");
dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Opa, funcionou! Valeu.

Comment: Só tenho um problema, quando eu volto da intent onde mostro os detalhes desse boleto, a dialog não finaliza, só se eu clicar fora da tela. Tem alguma forma que possa colocar o dialog.dimiss();

Comment: @rodrigo.oliveira, de acordo com a sua lógica, o `dialog.dismiss();` deve ser chamado quando o envio do boleto for finalizado. Porém, no seu código, você está apenas mostrando o dialog quando o usuário registra um listener para a lista, portanto, vc inicia o dialog, mas n tem o controle de quando finalizá-lo. Seria interessante vc dar uma lida em [Async Tasks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)